# How can i create edges (links) and node in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I would like to create a graph. To do this, I have created a JSON file. The Skills (java, python, HTML, json) should be the links and the index (KayO, BenBeck) should be the nodes. Also the node must not fall below a certain minimum size and must not become too large.

After that, I would like to be able to call up the list of publications on the right-hand side by clicking on the node. The currently selected node in the visualisation should be highlighted.

I have already implemented from this example (https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8). But unfortunately I can't get any further.

The error message I always get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

This is what my issue currently looks like:[image]

The JSON file:

```
const persona = {
    "KayO": {
      firstname: "Kay",
      lastname: "Ohran",
      Birthdate: "11.09.64",
      Hobby: "footbal",
      City: "California",
      skills: "java, python, HTML, json",
    },
    BenBeck: {
      firstname: "Ben",
      lastname: "Beckamm",
      Birthdate: "03.95.87",
      Hobby: "programming",
      City: "New York",
      skills: "css, ruby, php, training, simulator, java, web, webgl, json",
    },
    Borea: {
      skills: "patent, java, Swifts, Matlab, training, head-mounted-display, HMD, SQL, games",
      firstname: "Boren",
      lastname: "Armin",
      Birthdate: "22.04.94",
      Hobby: "footbal",
      City: "London",
    },
    BeattieH: {
      firstname: "Beattie",
      lastname: "Hod",
      Birthdate: "11.05.57",
      Hobby: "sleeping",
      City: "Texas",
      skills: "Oculus Rift, Unity, HCI, design, CAD, HMD",
    },
    BeierDad: {
      firstname: "Beier",
      lastname: "Dadu",
      Birthdate: "18.07.54",
      Hobby: "nothing",
      City: "Berlin",
      skills: "design, web, css, Matlab, simulation, manufacturing, ship design, ship building",
    },
    BSzavaiEl: {
      skills:"training, power plant, immersive, java, head-mounted displays, HMD, unity, oculus rift, games",
      firstname: "Szaski",
      lastname: "El mino",
      Birthdate: "25.09.88",
      Hobby: "language learning",
      City: "Berlin",
    },
    BellWeins: {
      skills: "speech recognition, dialog, json",
      firstname: "Bella",
      lastname: "Weinsetine",
      Birthdate: "01.01.90",
      Hobby: "drawing",
      City: "Peru",
    },
    BerndtLukas: {
      firstname: "Berndt",
      lastname: "Lukas",
      Birthdate: "22.02.96",
      Hobby: "fitness",
      City: "London",
      skills: "css, ship design, modelling, CAD, ship building, design, discarded-duplicate",
    },
    Bjoernese: {
      firstname: "Bjoerne",
      lastname: "Nessi",
      Birthdate: "11.09.81",
      Hobby: "gardening",
      City: "Mingguang",
      skills: "Swifts, touch, multi-touch, css, HCI, MMI, ship design, ship building, design",
    },
    BlumBroll: {
      firstname: "Blum",
      lastname: "Brolle",
      Birthdate: "22.06.91",
      Hobby: "Homebrewing",
      City: "Chizhou",
      skills: "augmented reality, json, under water, ocean, css, games",
    },
    BoltRod: {
      firstname: "Bolt",
      lastname: "Rody",
      Birthdate: "05.05.89",
      Hobby: "DJing",
      City: "Nanping",
      skills: "Swifts, speech recognition, multimodal, object interaction, games",
    },
    BoltHerra: {
      firstname: "Bolt",
      lastname: "Herra",
      Birthdate: "22.03.98",
      Hobby: "Babysitting",
      City: "Roseau",
      skills: "Swifts, two hands, multimodal, speech recognition, eye tracking, SQL",
    },
    YinYang: {
      skills: "Swifts, multimodal, techniques, games",
      firstname: "Yin",
      lastname: "Yang",
      Birthdate: "01.01.55",
      Hobby: "Wine tasting",
      City: "San Miguel",
    }
  };
```

Unfortunately I can't manage to create a node and link graph with the given JSON file.These are my actual coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Graph_Tutorial</title>
  <script src="persona.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 50px;
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    h2 {
      clear: both;
    }

    svg {
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #detail_box {
      float: left;
      width: 500px;
      height: 580px;
      overflow: auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-size: 9pt;
      margin-left: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #eee;
    }

    circle {
      fill: #0050aa;
    }

    .links {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

```
<body>
  <p>Tutorial <i>Directed Graph</i>, self-teaching</p>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>

  <svg width="800" height="600"></svg>
  <div id="detail_box"></div>

  <script>
    const bib = persona;
    console.table(bib);

    const graph = {nodes: [{id: "a"}, {id: "b"}], links: [{source: "a", target: "b"}]};

    const linkColor = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range(["#eee", "#000"]);

    const svg = d3.select("svg");
    const width = +svg.attr("width");
    const height = +svg.attr("height");

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


    d3.d3.json('/', function(err, data) {
      if(error) throw error;
      var link = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke", "#aaa");

    var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));

    node.append("title").text(d => d.id);

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
      node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    }
    });

    function dragstarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.y;
    }

    function dragended(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      event.subject.fx = null;
      event.subject.fy = null;
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Replace `d3.d3.json` with `d3.json`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky - Sorry i didnt see that. But know i have two other Error Messages: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: `'/' `is not a valid file path

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky:  Ive changed it thx. Know my code looks like this: `d3.json('persona.js', function(err, data)`.  Know its the next Error Message "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0". As i know the data that I'm loading is in JSON form.

Comment: JSON file cannot start with `const persona = {`. It should start with `{`

Comment: Is there another way without removing `const persona` ? I just want to create a graph that connects the skills of each person. The nodes are the names of the persons like "KayO", "BenBeck", "Borea" and so on. The links are then the skills ("java, python, HTML, json and so on") that are to be connected with each other.

Comment: Another way is to put `const persona = {` into a JS file and use it as a hard-coded variable instead of loading a JSON file in runtime. The good practice is to load JSON, and a JSON should comply to the format.

Comment: Is there also a way to create/force a graph without changing the JSON file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232480/discussion-between-michael-rovinsky-and-ashur-ragna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file should be of format:

```json
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Bjoerne",
      "lastName": "Nessi",
      "birthDate": "11.09.81",
      "hobby": ["Gardening", "Catering", "Psychology"],
      "city": "Mingguang",
      "skills": ["CSS", "HCI", "MMI"],
    },
    ...
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": 1, "target": 2}, ...
  ]
}
```